# How to add continue button if device is desktop else redirect page to start with desktop

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, device-detection

I am developing a game website.This game only works on desktop.So i decide to know the device type of user.
So far i am able to detect the device type.
If the user is on mobile then redirect to a page saying start the game in your desktop or laptop(example mobile.html).If the user is on desktop then redirect to the game page (example game.html).(I have already developed mobile.html and game.html).

I want the script to work at background and detect the device and redirect to a page depending on device type(for mobile - mobile.html for desktop - game.html)

Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/J26yC/

Script for detecting device

```
(function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;a=window.device,window.device={},c=window.document.documentElement,j=window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),device.ios=function(){return device.iphone()||device.ipod()||device.ipad()},device.iphone=function(){return d("iphone")},device.ipod=function(){return d("ipod")},device.ipad=function(){return d("ipad")},device.android=function(){return d("android")},device.androidPhone=function(){return device.android()&&d("mobile")},device.androidTablet=function(){return device.android()&&!d("mobile")},device.blackberry=function(){return d("blackberry")||d("bb10")||d("rim")},device.blackberryPhone=function(){return device.blackberry()&&!d("tablet")},device.blackberryTablet=function(){return device.blackberry()&&d("tablet")},device.windows=function(){return d("windows")},device.windowsPhone=function(){return device.windows()&&d("phone")},device.windowsTablet=function(){return device.windows()&&d("touch")&&!device.windowsPhone()},device.fxos=function(){return(d("(mobile;")||d("(tablet;"))&&d("; rv:")},device.fxosPhone=function(){return device.fxos()&&d("mobile")},device.fxosTablet=function(){return device.fxos()&&d("tablet")},device.meego=function(){return d("meego")},device.cordova=function(){return window.cordova&&"file:"===location.protocol},device.nodeWebkit=function(){return"object"==typeof window.process},device.mobile=function(){return device.androidPhone()||device.iphone()||device.ipod()||device.windowsPhone()||device.blackberryPhone()||device.fxosPhone()||device.meego()},device.tablet=function(){return device.ipad()||device.androidTablet()||device.blackberryTablet()||device.windowsTablet()||device.fxosTablet()},device.desktop=function(){return!device.tablet()&&!device.mobile()},device.portrait=function(){return window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth>1},device.landscape=function(){return window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth<1},device.noConflict=function(){return window.device=a,this},d=function(a){return-1!==j.indexOf(a)},f=function(a){var b;return b=new RegExp(a,"i"),c.className.match(b)},b=function(a){return f(a)?void 0:c.className+=" "+a},h=function(a){return f(a)?c.className=c.className.replace(a,""):void 0},device.ios()?device.ipad()?b("ios ipad tablet"):device.iphone()?b("ios iphone mobile"):device.ipod()&&b("ios ipod mobile"):b(device.android()?device.androidTablet()?"android tablet":"android mobile":device.blackberry()?device.blackberryTablet()?"blackberry tablet":"blackberry mobile":device.windows()?device.windowsTablet()?"windows tablet":device.windowsPhone()?"windows mobile":"desktop":device.fxos()?device.fxosTablet()?"fxos tablet":"fxos mobile":device.meego()?"meego mobile":device.nodeWebkit()?"node-webkit":"desktop"),device.cordova()&&b("cordova"),e=function(){return device.landscape()?(h("portrait"),b("landscape")):(h("landscape"),b("portrait"))},i="onorientationchange"in window,g=i?"orientationchange":"resize",window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener(g,e,!1):window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent(g,e):window[g]=e,e()}).call(this);
      console.log("device.mobile() === %s", device.mobile());
```

Comment: why is the code minified?

Comment: I have taken the code from http://matthewhudson.me/projects/device.js/.

Comment: Didn't you see the link?! https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js There's a not minified version

Comment: Instead of linking to device.min.js i added the script in the html page itself.